# Mules in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was under the impression from the information on the Minecraft wiki etc. that mules had all 3 stats (HP, Jump, and Speed) varied like horses do, rather than having a fixed jump height and speed like donkeys. Yet every mule I've bred (seven or eight of them now) has had the exact same speed and jump. Is this just a really weird coincidence? I did read that mules are incapable of being AS GOOD as a horse, so if they don't have fixed stats, what is the "best possible mule" I could breed?

Answer (score 2):

The [Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mule#Jump_strength) also states:

> Other jump strengths can be found in bred mules, depending on the statistics of the parents (as explained later)."

Bred mules are different from egg spawned mules is what that means. Bred mules stats can vary, but I still haven't figured out the limit yet either. I can tell you it's not in the wiki though.

Answer (score 1):

On the Minecraft wiki it says

"Mules' speed is always 0.175; the player's normal walking speed is 0.1"

"Mules' jump strength is always 0.5, which is enough to clear 1 9⁄16 blocks."

Health can range from 15-30 but is normally 22-23

Comment: I'm pretty sure that info is for donkeys. My mules can all jump about 2.5 blocks and have a speed that is faster than a sprint.

Comment: It says that Donkeys and Mules have the same Jump and Speed stats on the Wiki. Horses however can jump up to 5 blocks.